# Can't drop in on Echo, but I can call it

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I'm trying out the new intercom features of the Alexa devices and when I try to drop in I get this message from Alexa:

"to drop in on one of your devices, go to the alexa app, choose your contact name and enable drop in"

the problem is that it already says drop in is turned on for the device.

if I say "call kitchen echo"  she says "okay, calling kitchen echo"

(note that even though that seems to work, I've yet to be able to talk through it this way, using the intercom)

is there any difference in intent for calling vs dropping in?   or is just two ways of getting her to do the same thing?

Maybe my devices just don't have the latest update on them yet?  Is there any way to tell or check for updates.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I read that calling requires the receiver to answer the call, but dropping in does not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about Alexa and the Amazon Echo. Not programming related.

Answer (score 2):

People its super vague how to do this but I figured it out.  You have to enable drop-in on yourself as a contact. Whih makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I *just now* got an update to the Amazon Alexa app that made drop in work!

I went to the Apple App Store and there was an update to the Alexa App there.

I opened it and it asked me if I wanted to enable drop in.  I did and then I could immediately drop in from my office echo dot to my home echo.  The receiving end did not have to answer.

Documentation is at http://smile.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_bc_nav?ie=UTF8&nodeId=202156840

Answer (score 0):

There is also an update to the Android Alexa app as of today which also brings up the prompt to enable it.

I had the same problem but just updated the app and enabled it and now it works correctly throughout the house.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, looks I was also just a tad early and wasn't fully updated into the program. Talk about cutting edge :)   I got this today and now its working.

[image]